# androidで、コンストラクタに引数があるVMを、ActivityとFragment間で共有する方法

Tags: android, kotlin

sharedViewModelを扱いたい。そのVMはコンストラクタで引数を受け取る。
これviewModelsとかactivityViewModelsでどうかけばいいでしょうか？

```
class MyViewModel(val a: Int): ViewModel() {
  class Factory constructor(private val a: Int): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return MyViewModel(this.a) as T
    }
  }
}

class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
  // viewModels is fragment-ktx package
  val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels { MyViewModel.Factory(a = 1) }
}

class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    val viewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels() // raise Cannot create an instance of class com.example.myapp.MyViewModel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### 原因

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary?hl=ja#(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment).activityViewModels(kotlin.Function0)

> Returns a property delegate to access parent activity's ViewModel, if factoryProducer is specified then ViewModelProvider.Factory returned by it will be used to create ViewModel first time. Otherwise, the activity's androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory will be used.

google翻訳

> 親アクティビティのViewModelにアクセスするためのプロパティデリゲートを返します。factoryProducerが指定されている場合、それによって返されるViewModelProvider.Factoryは、ViewModelの最初の作成に使用されます。 それ以外の場合は、アクティビティのandroidx.activity.ComponentActivity.getDefaultViewModelProviderFactoryが使用されます。

とあるので、エラーの原因は、以下のナノではないかと推察します

- ActivityのViewModel取得よりもFragmentのViewModel取得が先にはしった
- ActivityにはまだViewModelが取得されていないため、FragmentのactivityViewModelsはviewModelの最初の作成の処理が走る
- FragmentのactivityViewModelsは引数が無いため親ActivityのgetDefaultViewModelProviderFacyoryを使ってViewModelを生成しようとする
- 親ActivityのgetDefaultViewModelProviderFacyoryはデフォルトのままで、カスタムFactoryではない(viewModelsを使っているからと言ってdefaultViewModelProviderFactoryが変わったりはしていない模様)
- デフォルトのViewModelProviderFacyoryは引数のあるViewModel::classが指定された場合にinstance生成に失敗する

### 対策

ActivityのetDefaultViewModelProviderFacyoryをoverrideしてcustomのFactoryをreturnするように変更する

```
class MyViewModel(val a: Int): ViewModel() {
  class Factory constructor(private val a: Int): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return MyViewModel(this.a) as T
    }
  }
}

class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
  // viewModels is fragment-ktx package
-  val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels { MyViewModel.Factory(a = 1) }
+  val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

+  override fun getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
+    return MyViewModel.Factory(a = 1)
+  }
}

class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    val viewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels() // 成功！ そしてshareされている!

}
```